# Highlighting a 'li' element in 'ul' with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On [this page](http://sample.srinformatics.nl)  you will see my page. I made have a menu. I wanted to make it more clear that this menu is a menu by highlighting the links on hover. While I normally would use JavaScript, jQuery sounded more simple to implement since it has `.hover`. So to highlight the elements from the list, I added this script:

```
<script>
    $("li").hover(
        function(){
            $(this).css("background-color", "#525252");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#FFF");
        }
    );
</script>
```

In my understanding of jQuery, the first function embedded in the hover() function is run when the user is hovering over the li-element. The second function is run when the mouse leaves the li-element. [jQuery API-link](http://api.jquery.com/hover/). The added script however doesn't seem to do anything at all.

My first try was to change the first line

```
$("li")
```

because this might not be the correct approach. This because it is a `ul` `li` so I tried `ul` `li` instead of just `li`.

The second solution was to use addClass but to make another class sounded a bit redundant to me. So I decided to not use this.

Last I tried to add an alert to see if the code is ran at all on hover. This is the case. When I added an alert in the code and hovered over the li-element the alert was not triggered. So to my understanding the faulty code is only one line:

```
$("li").hover()
```

But I haven't found what exactly is faulty here.

The HTML code for the menu is the following:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><strong><em><u>Main Menu</u></em></strong></li>
        <li onclick="moveDiv('home');">Home</li>
        <li onclick="moveDiv('profile')">Profile</li>
        <li onclick="moveDiv('news')">News</li>
        <li onclick="moveDiv('forums')">Forums</li>
        <li onclick="moveDiv('webshop')">Web Shop</li>
        <li onclick="moveDiv('status')">Status</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS sheet:

```
#menu ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    clear: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #525252;
}

#menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #525252;
}
```

Comment: post your css. so we can have a look.

Comment: By the way, wrap all your jquery in `$(function() { YOUR CODE GOES HERE });`. [Read more here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others said, wait for the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) to finish loading. You can put the script at the end of the page, or a more robust solution would be to wrap your code in `$(document).ready()` function, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").hover(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#525252");
    }, function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#FFF");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) instead:

```
li:hover {
    background-color:#525252
}
```

Comment: This is not supported by IE 6 and since too many people don't update their browser it will give problems for these people

Comment: IE6? what kind of pizza is that? You just don't want to make your design working for people with IE6. it's almost impossible to make it look nice.

Comment: With IE7 + IE6 in the 0.X% market share, I wouldn't bother with it anymore. http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201305-201306-bar

Comment: @PSR: you could potentially have got voted down for the syntax error `":`, should have been `:`) and the effect error (`li :hover`, should have been `li:hover`) in what you posted originally. I don't know, though.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the overhead of something like jQuery for this. CSS has some behavioural features through it's pseudo classes: http://jsfiddle.net/T4aNf/

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#menu li a {
    background: red;
}
#menu li a:hover {
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the DOM to be ready or put your script just before closing body tag:

(I checked your source code and, yes, this is your problem. You are setting it in head section.)

```
$(function () {
    $("li").hover(

    function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#525252");
    },

    function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#FFF");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your JavaScript code **before** the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) finishes loading. Wrap your JavaScript like this:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("li").hover(
            function(){
                $(this).css("background-color", "#525252");
            },
            function() {
                $(this).css("background-color", "#FFF");
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

`$()` is a shorthand for jQuery's [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.